# Delphi iOS - Detect KeyDown of Done button

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

How can I detect the press of the "Done" button on the virtual keyboard in Delphi when using iOS? Button in the upper right corner that closed virtual keyboard.

Comment: Use the OnVirtualKeyboardHidden event of TForm. It won't matter whether the user tapped the Done button, or it was hidden for some other reason; the same code is called.

Comment: There could be another way, however it involves modifying code in FMX.VirtualKeyboard.iOS, which you might want to avoid. It may help to describe exactly *why* you want to detect the Done button being pressed (as opposed to the control losing focus, or whatever), because there may be alternatives

Comment: I always tap "Done" button and I expect this is be the end of the action. I think the user expects the same.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment in your question, you'd need to modify the FMX.VirtualKeyboard.iOS unit. These steps should have you most of the way to your solution:

Create a unit to define a TMessage descendant, e.g:

```
unit VirtualKeyboardMessages;

interface

uses
  System.Messaging;

type
  TVirtualKeyboardDoneClickedMessage = class(TMessage);

implementation

end.
```

Make a copy of FMX.VirtualKeyboard.iOS and save it in your project folder. Modify the unit to include the unit above, e.g.:

```
implementation

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.TypInfo, System.Generics.Collections, System.UITypes, System.Types, 
  System.Messaging, System.Math, Macapi.ObjectiveC, Macapi.ObjCRuntime, Macapi.Helpers,
  iOSapi.CocoaTypes, iOSapi.Foundation, iOSapi.UIKit, iOSapi.CoreGraphics,
  FMX.Types, FMX.VirtualKeyboard, FMX.Platform, FMX.Forms, FMX.Platform.iOS, FMX.Consts, FMX.Helpers.iOS,
  // Add this to the uses clause
  VirtualKeyboardMessages;
```

Add a DoneButtonClicked method to the IKeyboardEvents interface and TKeyboardEventHandler class:

```
  IKeyboardEvents = interface(NSObject)
  ['{72D3A7FD-DDE3-473D-9750-46C072E7B3B7}']
    // code snipped for brevity, and to avoid copyright issues

    // Add this method
    procedure DoneButtonClicked; cdecl;
  end;

  TKeyboardEventHandler = class(TOCLocal)
  strict private type
    TKeyboardState = (Shown, Hidden);
  private
    FKeepFocus: Boolean;
    // code snipped for brevity, and to avoid copyright issues

    // Add this method
    procedure DoneButtonClicked; cdecl;
  end;

procedure TKeyboardEventHandler.DoneButtonClicked;
begin
  HideVirtualKeyboard;
  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SendMessage(Self, TVirtualKeyboardDoneClickedMessage.Create);
end;
```

Modify the RefreshToolbarButtons method:

```
procedure TCocoaVirtualKeyboardService.RefreshToolbarButtons;
var
  I: Integer;
  B: UIBarButtonItem;
  AutoReleasePool: NSAutoReleasePool;
begin
  // code snipped for brevity, and to avoid copyright issues

      //Hide button
      if FHideButton = nil then
      begin
        FHideButton := TUIBarButtonItem.Create;
        FHideButton.setTitle(StrToNSStr(SEditorDone));
        FHideButton.setStyle(UIBarButtonItemStyleDone);
        FHideButton.setTarget(FKeyboardHandler.GetObjectID);
        // Following line commented out from original code:
        // FHideButton.setAction(sel_getUid('HideVirtualKeyboard'));
        // Following line added:
        FHideButton.setAction(sel_getUid('DoneButtonClicked'));
      end;

  // code snipped for brevity, and to avoid copyright issues
end;
```

Then you will need to subscribe to the TVirtualKeyboardDoneClickedMessage in your form, which will need to use the VirtualKeyboardMessages unit, above. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Why you comment this method ?FHideButton.setAction(sel_getUid('HideVirtualKeyboard'));

Comment: Because the DoneButtonClicked method replaces it

Answer (score 0):

```
uses VirtualKeyboardMessages;
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  {...}  
private
    { Private declarations }
    MessageManager: TMessageManager;
    SubscriptionId: Integer;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MessageManager := TMessageManager.DefaultManager;
  SubscriptionId := MessageManager.SubscribeToMessage( TVirtualKeyboardDoneClickedMessage, procedure(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage)
begin
  ShowMessage('Done');
end);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TMessageManager.DefaultManager.Unsubscribe(TVirtualKeyboardDoneClickedMessage, SubscriptionId);
end;
```

// Currently is good solution if you have only one TEdit on the form. But if you have multiple  then is problem . And if you using visual dialog in this case "Showmessage" then virtual keyboard not hiding.

Comment: Why is it a problem if there are multiple edits? Also, why are you using ShowMessage when Done is clicked?

Comment: Because it is not determined what kind of TEdit. I use "done capture" for webbrowse (if "done" then webbrowser.navigate(edit.text);) but if web page have edit and i again tap "done" then same event called again. Showmessage or simular the only way to communicate with the user.

Comment: You can check whether or not an edit has focus by using IsFocused. Better yet, check exactly what has focus by using the ActiveControl property. Why do you want to communicate anything to the user when they've tapped "Done"?

Comment: It seems you just want to know what control has focus when the keyboard is hidden (the control will remain focused when tapping the "Done" button). This is easily achieved by using the OnVirtualKeyboardHidden event and examining the ActiveControl property

Comment: Yes, it's better than creating a new class